# Remove alpha from vertex color

Tags: transparency, vertex-colors

I have some meshes that I baked the materials in to vertex color and it works fine. But when I export to FBX, all the vertex colors are RGBA while all the alpha values are 1.0. Is there a way to get rid of the alpha component of the vertex colors?